# VBA can't take reference of an object

Tags: vba

I've got an array I need to populate with references to labels on a display.  I've managed to reduce my issue to a MWE below:

```
Private Sub Button1_Released()
    Me.TestLabel.Caption = "Button1"
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Released()
    Dim o As MSForms.Label
    Set o = Me.TestLabel
    o.Caption = "Button2"
End Sub
```

The code for button1 works while buttton2 fails with message, "Method Caption of object ILabelControl failed (0x80010105)".

TypeName(Me.TestLabel) returns "Label".  When I change my Dim to "Label" instead of "MSForms.Label" I get behavior that looks like an uninitialized variable being accessed.  For example: sometimes button2 will produce chinese characters in the label, often nothing happens but the VBA module will crash.

I have tried removing and restoring the typelib reference with no effect.  I have tried changing the reference from the office v16 fm20.dll to the syswow64 v14 fm20.dll with no effect.

This is a previously functioning application developed on one machine and moved to another.  I have considered recreating the displays, but the MWE comes from a new display, created on the new machine, with just a label and two buttons.

Pretty stuck here.

ed:  changing the dim from MSForms.Label to Object worked

Comment: Is this VBA? I am not familiar with aButton Released event. There is a MouseUp event, but no Released event.

Comment: I agree with Tim. Are the subs called by an event or by code?

Comment: What happens if you just use `Dim o As Object`?

Comment: This worked.  Thank you.  For the others, the hosting application is FactoryTalk View SE, it's just standard event handlers.